# How to get the time that I spent in a url?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, webbrowser-control, scenebuilder

I made a java simple web browser. 
I want to know how how much time I visited in a particular web pages.
Fo example, if I visit a link like stackoverflow.com and stayed here few minutes, after exit this site I want to be able to see the total time spent here in the console. 
Heres is my main java file-

```
package browser;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Browser extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("webfxml.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and this is the controller-

```
package browser;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class WebfxmlController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextField txt;
    @FXML
    private Button bt;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anc; 
    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        WebEngine we=webView.getEngine();
        we.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> enter= new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                we.load(txt.getText().startsWith("http://")?txt.getText():"http://"+txt.getText());

            }
        };
        txt.setOnAction(enter);
        bt.setOnAction(enter);

        we.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    txt.setText(newValue);
                }
            });


    }    

    @FXML
    private void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        //txt.setText("Webview");
    }

    }
```

and this is the webfxml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anc" prefHeight="560.0" prefWidth="784.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="browser.WebfxmlController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txt" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="625.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="145.0" />
      <Button fx:id="bt" layoutX="654.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Go" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="62.0" />
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="509.0" prefWidth="784.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="6.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Add a listener to the Location property of the WebEngine

Comment: @rollback can you tell me in details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `long startTime, endTime, druation;` and `int startRecording = 0;`

```
@FXML
private TextField txt;
@FXML
private Button bt;
@FXML
private AnchorPane anc; 
@FXML
private WebView webView;

long startTime, endTime, duration;
int startRecording = 0;//This helps you to not try to get the duration the first time the button is pressed.
```

> In the `EventHandler` start recording time when the `Button` is pressed.

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> enter= new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {                
            we.load(txt.getText().startsWith("http://")?txt.getText():"http://"+txt.getText());               
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    };
```

> When the `locationProperty` change, record the end time. Next, calculate and display the duration.

```
we.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                if(startRecording > 0)
                {
                    endTime = System.nanoTime();
                    duration = endTime - startTime;
                    if((duration / 1000000000) >= 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("duration: " + (duration / 1000000000) + " seconds");
                    }
                }
                startRecording++;
                txt.setText(newValue);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This works only when the location property is changed! If i scroll fb news feed then it not showing the proper duration! :(

Comment: It meets the requirement you set in your question. You said `For example, if I visit a link like stackoverflow.com and stayed here few minutes, after exit this site I want to be able to see the total time spent here in the console.`

Comment: Edit your question and be more precise.

Comment: Thank you. I already up voted and accepted your answer. but it your be very good for me if you say how to handle in other website like youtube or facebook. They dont give the proper duration

Comment: If the answer does not satisfy your question, do not accept it. You should rewrite your question and I can try to build a better answer from the updated question.